Get the list of all fine tunable models from GCP
I want to return the list of all fine tunable models from Vertex AI from GCP. To do so I used the ModelServiceClient from aiplatform library but I get not model : [ [], null, null ]
I used the following code :
const modelDisplayName = 'fineTunedTest';
    const { ModelServiceClient } = aiplatform.v1;

    const location = 'us-central1';
    const project = 'projectID';
    const model = 'text-bison@001';

    const modele = new ModelServiceClient({
      apiEndpoint: `${location}-aiplatform.googleapis.com`,
      keyFilename: config.vector_store_key_filename,
    });
    console.log(
      'modele',
      await modele.listModels({
        parent: `projects/${project}/locations/${location}`,
      })
    );

Does ModelServiceClient object only return already fine tuned model ?
Docs

hey , did your problem get solved ?

No I still have the issue. Do you have a solution to this ?

This code only return fine tuned models and not base model like I want
